# How can I nest these two SQL queries in MS Access 2007?

Tags: sql, ms-access, nested

I have a table called baskets with these columns:

- basket (name of the basket)
- colour (colour of the basket)
- apples (the number of apples in the basket)
- bananas (the number of bananas in the basket)
- oranges (the number of oranges in the basket)
- pears (the number of pears in the basket)
- peaches (the number of peaches in the basket)

With Query1, I determine the total number of fruit in each basket and I also include the colour of each basket:

```
SELECT basket, colour, apples+bananas+oranges+pears+peaches AS fruit
FROM baskets;
```

Query1 consists of three columns:

- basket
- colour
- fruit (total number of fruit in the basket)

With Query2, I determine the average number of fruits there are in all baskets of each colour by drawing the information from the result of Query1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        candidate.colour,
        candidate.fruit
            (SELECT AVG(fruit)
                 FROM Query1 AS average
                 WHERE average.colour = candidate.colour) AS fruit
    FROM Query1 AS candidate;
```

Query2 consists of two columns:

- colour
- fruit

Is it possible to nest these queries so that I may obtain the result of Query2 with only one query?

Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT colour, AVG(apples+bananas+oranges+pears+peaches) AS fruit
FROM baskets
GROUP by colour;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the total fruit by colour of basket you would do something like this:

```
SELECT colour, SUM(apples+bananas+oranges+pears+peaches) AS totalfruit
FROM baskets
GROUP By colour
```

Comment: Thanks, DJ. I made a mistake. I meant average number of fruit.